# SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ImageUrl', table 'Project.dbo.Products'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Porque tengo este error?

SqlException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'ImageUrl', table 'Project.dbo.Products'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails

```
public class Product
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Imagen")]
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "El campo {0} es obligatorio.")]
    public string ImageUrl { get; set; }

    [Display(Name = "Descripcion del producto")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    //TODO: replace the correct URL for the image
    public string ImageFullPath => string.IsNullOrEmpty(ImageUrl)
        ? null
        : $"https://TBD.azurewebsites.net{ImageUrl.Substring(1)}";
```

Comment: Te dice que no podes insertar un valor null en ese column

Comment: entiendo, pero como lo soluciono? formule mal la pregunta :/

Comment: O modificas que tu base permita valores null en esa column o no permitis que le lleguen null desde tu codigo de c#

Comment: Lectura obligada: https://es.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/4433/822

Answer (score 0):

Le estas pasando `null` cuando tu cadena es vacia, podes cambiarlo por una cadena vacia.

```
public string ImageFullPath => string.IsNullOrEmpty(ImageUrl)
        ? string.Empty
        : $"https://TBD.azurewebsites.net{ImageUrl.Substring(1)}";
```

Comment: ahhh bien, ahora que ya hice la migracion como hago?

Comment: no se de que migracion hablas, no puedo adivinar.